# Visual Basic 6 data structures

Tags: ms-access, vba, data-structures, vb6

What are all the build in data structures for VB6 (Microsoft Access) ?  I know there are arrays, but are there other more modern data structures?

Comment: Are you asking about VB6, or about VBA in Access?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It has a `Dictionary`: [Does VBA have Dictionary Structure?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/915317/does-vba-have-dictionary-structure/915323)

And `Collection`: [VBA: Resources for Python Programmer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76882/vba-resource-for-python-programmer)

Comment: The dictionary is *not* a VBA data structure, but it's usable in VBA simply because a COM object (the scripting runtime) provides it.

Comment: @David W. Fenton  is of course correct. Both of those COM objects are commonly used in VBA.

Answer (score 5):

Disconnected recordsets can also be useful: [syncing two lists with VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/226978/syncing-two-lists-with-vba)

Answer (score 3):

The excellent book Hardcore Visual Basic by Bruce McKinney includes some code for creating linked lists, stacks, etc. as part of its introduction to object-based programming with VB6. The book is now available [free online](http://vb.mvps.org/hardcore/).

Answer (score 2):

I don't think I understand the question. When I read it, I thought of:

- Arrays
- Collections
- Types
- Enums

and so forth. Not sure if I'd consider standalone class modules as part of the answer, as they can have any structure you want, rather than being a particular data structure. And, of course, VBA being COM-based, it can use any data structure from compatible COM objects. This may or may not require a type library (depends on the COM object's implementation).

Comment: Yah my first instinct was to explain Types.

Answer (score 1):

You can also create your own (better accessibility/performance XML collections) in this way:

[MS XML Collections](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa239702(VS.60).aspx)

Also consider using hashtables:

[Hash Tables](http://www.kellyethridge.com/vbcorlib/hashtabletutorial1.shtml)

Answer (score 1):

I written quite a lot of code in VB6 and for sure I used Dictionary and Collection classes a lot. But I still think that they are not enough in many cases, that's why I advise you to take a look at this library:

http://sourceforge.net/projects/vbcorlib/

that it's a port of .NET libraries to VB6.